# Embedded System Client - SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, http-post, client-server

I am working on a product that would be http POSTing some data to my server everyday. The server doesn't send any data/REQUESTS to my device (other than the HTTP status). I use a redpine wireless module RS9113 that does the connectivity piece for me. I want this communication to be **https** enabled and my web server already has a CA-issued certificate.

Question is :

1. When I do a POST from my embedded device, my understanding is that the SSL library would check the validity of the server certificate. Am I right ?
2. If my client doesnt need a certificate, does it mean the public key of the server is stored on the wireless module (and this is used for encryption everytime) ? I can guess that this is something I need to ask the redpine wireless folks, but can you give me a general idea how this works ?
3. In this setup, do I need to have any certificate ON my embedded device ? I am ok if anybody POSTs the data to the server because we have identifiers that would flush out the non-conforming structure of data. If there is no cert on the device and if we POST, does it mean that the data is encrypted from device-server ?

Bonus question : In this setup, if my cert on the server is renewed, will it cause any problems in sending the data ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the redpine wireless module, so take this response as a resolution of doubts about SSL in general

> When I do a POST from my embedded device, my understanding is that the SSL library would check the validity of the server certificate. Am I right ?

Yes, the SSL library should check that the issuer of the certificate (the root CA) or the certificate itself are present in the trust store. If you use a self-signed certificate or a CA that is not present in the truststore, you have to include the public key in the truststore

> If my client doesnt need a certificate, does it mean the public key of the server is stored on the wireless module (and this is used for encryption everytime) ?

The two things are not related. You need the public key of the server in the wireless module to establish trust. A client certificate would be needed if you use two-ways authentication. The client certificate is presented during SSL handshake to authenticate the client to the server

> In this setup, do I need to have any certificate ON my embedded device ?

No, if two ways authentication are not required

> If there is no cert on the device and if we POST, does it mean that the data is encrypted from device-server ?

The client certificate, if any, is not used to encrypt. Is used to authenticate during the initial handshake. The handshake stablish a symmetric key used to encrypt and decrypt the communication in both sides.

> In this setup, if my cert on the server is renewed, will it cause any problems in sending the data ?

Depending on the setup of the server certificate on your client truststore. If the new certificate is issued on the same side, it is enough to have imported the root CA. If you use self-signed certificate, you will need to import the new one